# Flutter: Recognise touch immediately

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to recognize a touch input immediately in Flutter? Normal buttons of course don't work since they trigger on lift off. The closest thing I could find was using onTapDown by the GestureDetector widget. But this only triggers after a short delay. 
Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try wrapping your widget with the `Listener` widget and use the `onPointerDown` property.

e.g.

```
Listener(
      child: Scaffold(),
      onPointerDown: (_) {},
)
```